# How to use discord.py remove_roles for many roles? (list of objects as an args)

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to remove all roles with one command.
 - Declaring empty list.
 - Creatintg list of actual roles
 - Getting object role and adding it to list.
 - Calling remove_roles with list of object roles.

```
x = []  
serverroles = ['blabla','piupiu','etc']  
for role in serverroles:  
    x.append(discord.utils.get(ctx.message.server.roles, name=role))
await client.remove_roles(ctx.message.author, x)
```

Getting error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'`
What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [`remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.remove_roles) documentation, you'll see that its function signature is:

```
remove_roles(member, *roles)
```

`*roles` means "zero or more arguments, which get put into a `tuple` called `roles`".  You can either supply these individually:

```
await client.remove_roles(member, role1, role2, role3)
```

or through unpacking.  In your case this would look like

```
await client.remove_roles(ctx.message.author, *x)
```

Comment: This works! Thank you for supporting newbie like me :D
Now i know about unpacking.